# Alias grep quote usage

Tags: shell, grep, alias, bashrc

I'm trying to make an alias in the `bashrc` file but having issues. I want the command to `grep` the access logs of our server for a particular IP address. My current entry is:

```
alias ip_usage='sudo grep "$1" /srv/logs/httpd/chris-server.com/access.log'
```

My shell usage is:

```
ip_usage 192.168.0.0
```

but this brings back all records in the access log.

I also tried inverting the quote usage but the performance was the same.

```
alias ip_usage="sudo grep '$1' /srv/logs/httpd/chris-server.com/access.log"
```

Running:

```
sudo grep '192.168.0.0' /srv/logs/httpd/chris-server.com/access.log
```

brings my back the records I want so it is something with my quotes and the value being passed in.

Comment: This sounds like something better suited to place into a function than an alias.

Comment: @DopeGhoti You were correct, a function was the correct route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first version of the quoting would be correct **except** that aliases don't do what you want.  You need a function:

```
ip_usage() { sudo grep "$1" /srv/logs/httpd/chris-server.com/access.log; }
```

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> Aliases  allow  a  string  to  be substituted for a word when it is used as the first word of a simple command.

In other words, aliases do string substitution.  They do not support manipulation of arguments.  Thus, referencing a first argument inside an alias via `$1` is not supported.

Also from `man bash`:

> A  shell function, defined as described above under SHELL GRAMMAR,
>   stores a series of commands for later execution.  When the name of a
>   shell function is used as a simple   command name, the list of
>   commands associated with that function name is executed.  Functions
>   are executed in the context of the current shell; no new process is 
>   created  to  interpret them (contrast this with the execution of a
>   shell script).  When a function is executed, the arguments to the
>   function become the positional parameters during its execution.  The
>   special parameter # is updated to reflect the change.  Special
>   parameter 0 is unchanged.  The first element of the FUNCNAME variable
>   is set to the
>          name of the function while the function is executing.

In other words, bash functions do support positional arguments.

#### Aside: Why an alias with $1 at the end might seem to work

Let's define an alias

```
$ alias e='echo $1'
```

Now, let's clear the shell's positional argument and run the alias:

```
$ set -- 
$ e a b c
a b c
```

It does what one might hope.

Notice, though, that there is a trap.  Let's set the shell's first positional argument:

```
$ set -- First
$ echo "$1"
First
```

Now, let's run our command again:

```
$ e a b c
First a b c
```

Here, it is clear that `$1` in an alias refers to the first shell's first argument, not the aliases first argument.

Comment: Strange, I have `alias svn_diff='svn diff --diff-cmd /usr/bin/diff -x "-i -b" $1'` working, where `$1` is a file path. I have confirmed this works for the `ip_usage`. I'm not following the difference between functions and aliases. It seems like the above example uses positional arguments.

Comment: @chris85 Yes, that works but only accident because the `$1` is at the end of the alias where the arguments you supply would appear (with or without the `$1` at the end).

Comment: @chris85 Very good.  Also, I just added a longer explanation to the answer of how aliases work with `$1`.